# É possível abrir arquivos PDF com o Python?

Tags: python, windows, pdf, sistema-operacional

É possível abrir arquivos com python? Literalmente, como por exemplo arquivos PDF's salvos em uma determinada pasta do computador?

Tentei utilizar bibliotecas, como o PyPDF2, mas ele não exibe o arquivo em si, apenas determinadas partes de texto.

Comment: Você procura visualizadores de PDF e PostScript.

Comment: Quando diz abrir, sim apenas pode abrir mas fazer a leitura é outra situação que exige outra programação destinada a ler em partes ou todo o arquivo.

Comment: Pacote PyMuPDF oferece uma infinidade de recursos para abrir e descriptografar PDF e uma dúzia de outros tipos de documentos para extrair e pesquisar texto, extrair imagens e gráficos vetoriais, salvar páginas de documentos como imagens e muito mais. dê uma olhada na documentação detalhada aqui: https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Você pode usar a biblioteca pandas

Answer (score 0):

Olá, se você quer literalmente abrir o arquivo em seu computador, como se tivesse clicado nele, terá que usar a biblioteca os, que faz operações no sistema operacional. Faça isso:

```
import os

os.startfile('local do arquivo')
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).